# Android: How to check if the wifi calling is supported by device or by the network, and turn on/off it programmatically

Tags: android, wifi

Is there a way to check if the device/network supports the Wi-Fi calling?
Is there a way to enable/disable it programmatically?

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: When you say "Wi-Fi calling" do you just mean does the device support "Wi-Fi" or something else? Also, when you say enable/disable programmatically, do you mean enabled/disable the Wi-Fi feature on a device or enable/disable Wi-Fi (similar to what the goggle does in a phone's Wi-Fi settings)?

Comment: When you say "Wi-Fi calling" do you just mean does the device support "Wi-Fi" or something else? 
--- I mean does the device support "Wi-Fi calling" functionality, and not the Wi-Fi, you can find more info about Wi-Fi calling here 
https://www.howtogeek.com/234608/how-to-enable-wi-fi-calling-on-an-android-phone/

Also, when you say enable/disable programmatically, do you mean enabled/disable the Wi-Fi feature on a device or enable/disable Wi-Fi
---No I mean to enable disable the Wi-Fi calling functionality, and not the device Wi-Fi